# web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction is not a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I use the `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` function, but it is not working.

This is code of problem

```
  var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount("<from address>");

  const txParams ={
      nonce:web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
      to : "<to address>",
      value : web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.01','ether')),
      gasPrice :web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('1','Gwei')),
      gasLimit:web3.utils.numberToHex('300000'),
      chainId :3          //Ropsten
  }
  const tx = new Tx(txParams);
  const privateKey = Buffer.from("<primary key>",'hex');
  tx.sign(privateKey);

  const serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
  console.log(serializedTx);
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx, function(err,txId){if(err){ console.log(' : ',txId)}});
```

I checked "serializedTx" log.

> 0xf86d827b7d843b9aca00830493e0944f16477b610cad87e1f506e42208bc36bce6aa4887f8b0a10e470000802aa016a1bc13133cbbfd0cdb5aa0da5e049e0eba3972b313ba69887970acecf2e11ba06b2fd1b9dad15959e271a1af8020fd9e4b1f089d8eb66f99c48988032c300f78

I think it is too long ...

And ether also could not be transferred.

And I tried from

```
web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether')
```

to

```
"web3.utils.toWei(0.01, 'ether')"
```

But It is err.

> error code is "Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors."

What is wrong and How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I find a method,and this problem disappeared! I just improve the web3's version to 1.0.0 or above.So maybe you can have a try.
Just like this:

```
npm install -g web3@1.0.0-beta.52
```